# function name cast to uint32_t

Tags: c, function, casting

I cannot understand this part of code can someone explain me what is going on?

I got a 2 functions:

```
void timer_irq_handler(void) {
   ....
}

void NVIC_SetVector(IRQn_Type IRQn, uint32_t vector) {
   ....
}
```

then I got something like this:

```
NVIC_SetVector(TIM_MST_IRQ, (uint32_t)timer_irq_handler);
```

I don't understand to cast void function to (uint32_t)

Comment: Thank you for quick respond, now I understand more but one more question to be completely educated. what is result of this casting? is it address of this pointer?

Comment: It's downright lethal if the system is a 64-bit system.  On a 32-bit system, the pointer will be transferred as a number — not particularly good practice, but it would probably 'work'.  The code should use `uintptr_t`; it will then work on machines where `sizeof(void *) == sizeof(void (*)(void))`, which is most (but not all) machines.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler uintptr_t can only store object pointers.

Comment: @2501: What are you saying that I didn't already say?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The thing I wrote in the above comment. To add: function pointers are not object pointers, maybe that confused you.

Comment: @2501: Well, I already covered the case where you can't use `uintptr_t` for function pointers, so I really don't see what your comment adds.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You seem to suggest that function pointers can be used if the mentioned condition is true. This is not correct.

Comment: @2501: I disagree.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Maybe you could point out the paragraphs that define conversions from function pointers to uintptr_t, and conversions from function pointers to void*. Since they don't exist, this behavior isn't defined.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That is not correct. Conversion between function pointers and object pointers are not defined in C.

Answer (score -1):

function name is a pointer, cast a pointer to uint32_t is fine in C.

Comment: Not on a 64-bit system: there a cast from pointer to `uint32_t` is one way; there's no way back to the original value when you've thrown half the bits away.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler   though it will drop some bits, but still can cast to. maybe some warning. C is dangerous.

Comment: I would like to add my question is about stm32 microprocessor with 32 bit architecture.